# Using PL/SQL associative arrays

Tags: oracle, plsql, bulkinsert

```
create or replace aArr is TABLE of varchar2 index by binary_integer;
create or replace bArr is TABLE of varchar2 index by binary_integer;

create or replace prc(oname aArr, iname bArr) as
begin

--Now i have two arrays
-- i want to insert or update into table using these two arrays
-- How can i do that with out using the loops.
-- is there any bulk insert or update.

end
```

Now I have two arrays. I want to insert or update into table using these two arrays. How can I do that with out using the loops? Is there any bulk insert or update?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have PL/SQL associative arrays, you can use bulk processing to insert the data into underlying database tables using FORALL.

The oracle documantation is here:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/forall_statement.htm

The syntax is similar to:

```
FORALL x IN INDICES OF <associative_array_name>
   -- DML (INSERT or UPDATE etc)
```

It's a bit of a generic answer but you have asked a very generic question.

Hope this helps...